# Can't go back to previous panel using "this.ownerCt.setActiveItem..." in Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I am having a very hard time understanding why i can't go back to the previous panel within my application. Enough talk, some code

```
appsDetails = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
layout: 'fit',
scroll: 'verticall',

initComponent: function() {

    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            ui: 'back',
            scope: 'this',
            handler: function() {

                console.log(this.ownerCt) //This returns "undefined"

                this.ownerCt.setActiveItem(this.prevCard, {
                    type: 'slide',
                    reverse: true,
                    scope: this,
                    after: function() {
                        this.destroy();
                    }
                })
            }
        }]
    }];

    this.items = [{
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        tpl: description,
        data: this.record.data
    }];

    appsDetails.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
});
```

I am getting to this view above by using this code below in the previous panel

```
selection: function(list, index) {

if (index[0] !== undefined) {
    var details = new appsDetails({
        homeCard: this.appsPanel,
        record: index[0],
    });

    this.setActiveItem(details, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'})
}
}
```

I have no problem getting to the desired panel but i can't come back the previous one.

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string object with value `'this'`. Change this line: `scope:'this'` in `scope:this`

Comment: Thanks i didn't see that :) Now that i am going back to the previous panel i noticed that i need to tap twice on the previously selected item in order to go back to it's description or once on another item to do so. Any idea?